# Should [rss] and [feed] tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

Should [rss](/questions/tagged/rss) and [feed](/questions/tagged/feed) tags be merged?

- [rss](/questions/tagged/rss)

  > For questions about the various RSS feeds provided by Stack Exchange sites.
- [feed](/questions/tagged/feed)

  > Use this tag for questions about Stack Exchange RSS feeds (existing or proposed) and the bot in chat that posts messages when preselected RSS feeds are updated

Comment: Just marking this as completed since the tags were synonymized a while ago (I assume). I've just merged them as well.

Comment: This has been completed don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it should. There is no use in keeping them both since they both cover the same topic, either the RSS feed or RSS feeds in chat (both tags are used for both topics).

I proposed a synonym. Feel free to support it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feed/synonyms.